# how to select value from month to month name in oracle database table in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I want to my database table date column to month, and wanted to calculate the data from month to month But, i getting this error again and again

```
SQL> desc fac_cus_chd
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 FDC                                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(9)
 WHDATE                                    NOT NULL DATE
 SL_NO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 ITEMCODE                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(11)
 DECCODE                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)
 GRADE                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
 QTY                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(9,2)
 UNIT                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
 CARTON                                             VARCHAR2(5)
 UPRICE                                             NUMBER(9,2)
 UPT                                                VARCHAR2(1)
 CARTON_DET                                         VARCHAR2(5)

SQL> select SUM(QTY)
     from fac_cus_chd
     where whdate between to_date(to_char('01-JAN-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') AND  to_date(to_char('31-DEC-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') ;
  2  /
select to_date(to_char('WHDATE', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') from fac_cus_chd
                       *
  ERROR at line 1:
  ORA-01722: invalid number
 SQL>
```

I want o have value like

```
Month         Qty 
Jan           200000
Feb           33,0000
Mar           34,0000 
APR            32293
May           242434
JUN            24242
JUL             24234
AUG            232423
SEP            242432
OCT            232342
NOV           33423
DEC           3233333
```

Comment: Which result do you expect?

Comment: I want to get the result in month, converted to date filed to month.

Comment: Get rid of single quotes around filed name. You can use double quotes if you like.

Comment: SQL> select to_date(to_char("WHDATE", 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') from fac_cus_chd
  2  /
select to_date(to_char("WHDATE", 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') from fac_cus_chd
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL>

Comment: @LitonBiswas: please edit your question to show us a few records of sample data and the result that you would expect (as text, no images).

Comment: the problem is - you are trying to convert the date to char, and then from that char to construct the date 
Oracle formatts a particular date into dd-mm-yyyy format, and then tries to construct a date form it considering that the char contains only Month, and fails
you do not need to perform the conversion twice, instead convert to char only by year/month and group values that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution would be something like that

```
with fac_cus_chd as(
select to_date('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 10 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('01-02-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 30 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('01-03-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 5 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('01-04-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 10 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 2 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('01-09-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 4 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('01-10-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 5 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('25-10-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 8 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('01-11-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 2 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('01-12-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 3 as qty from dual union all
select to_date('20-12-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as whdate, 7 as qty from dual
)

    select to_char(trunc(whdate, 'MON'), 'Mon') as month_name
         , sum(qty) as quantity
      from fac_cus_chd
     where trunc(WHDATE, 'MON') between to_date('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                                    and to_date('31-12-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  group by trunc(whdate, 'MON')
  order by trunc(whdate, 'MON')
```

you could then apply ordering etc

```
MONTH_NAME  QUANTITY
Jan     10
Feb     30
Mar     5
Apr     10
Jul     2
Sep     4
Oct     13
Nov     2
Dec     10
9 rows
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0d814b3181a006eb4e9c85e75d7593ec)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes enclosing `WHDATE`. Also TO_DATE() doesnt convert the column directly but reads the data in the format given like you have `DD-MM-YYYY`
below this ensures the data is read like this and converted to default date format of oracle

```
     TO_DATE(WHDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')


     TO_CHAR(WHDATE, 'MON')
       //this will give the desired
```